# Priority List with Heap Sort (Java)

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

I would like know if exists a Java native implementation for a Priority List using Heap Sort approach. If not, is there any recommended alternative?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html Did you try googling your exact question?

Comment: For me, the first Google result was `PriorityQueue`

Comment: What do you mean by "java native implementation"?

Comment: Please check this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021397/heap-sort-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for PriorityQueue says:

> "An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap."

And the source code PriorityQueue for (Java 6 onwards) has this comment:

> "Priority queue represented as a balanced binary heap ..."

Technically speaking, this is not [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).  However, the standard Heapsort algorithm is not appropriate to a priority queue: it is non-incremental (O(NlogN)).  What `PriorityQueue` does is incremental (O(logN) per queue insertion).

For more details, read the source code.  It is well commented.